# Using tie/knot as a verb in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

**Tie (verb):** 
to fasten together two ends of a piece of string or other long, thin material, or to (cause to) hold together with a long, thin piece of string, material, etc.

**Example:** 
- Could you tie this piece of string for me?

**Knot (verb):** 
 to tie in or with a knot:

**Example:** 
- He caught the rope and knotted it around a post.

Based on these definitions, what word as a verb can be used in a figurative sense in the following sentence:

> Language and culture are inseparably .............. to each other.

**Connotation:** "culture" and "language" are severely related to each other and each one has considerable influence into the other one.

I think, "tie" is a better choice and I can say:

> Language and culture are inseparably **tied** to each other.

But I don't know if a native would use this word in this sense. Meanwhile, I need to know whether "knot" can be used in this sense too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Language and culture are inseparably tied to each other.

I **would** use this sentence, but I agree with Edward Barnard that "connected" could be used instead. Remember that even in the purely physical realm, one can speak of two beams being tied together by bots or by crossbars. When used metaphorically, "tie" does primarily mean "connect". Even where the image is of joining two cords with a knot (as in "tie the knot" as an idiom for "get married") the emphasis is on the connection, not the method of making it.

I would not recast the example sentence to use "knot" as a verb. "Knot" tends to suggest complication and often confusion, as in "knotted hair", "a knotty problem" and those are not the image wanted here.

One might use "intertwined" to suggest separate strands that have joined into a single thing, particularly "inextricably intertwined".

Comment: inseparably tied is just one of many possibilities. And tied the verb comes from a tie, not from knotting a knot or tying a knot.

Answer (score 1):

Language and culture are inseparably .............. to each other.

= tied [as with **have a bond or tie" but not as in **tie a knot**]
= bound [as in bind, bound, bound, meaning going together or connected to each
  other]
= connected
= related
= joined

To have strong ties to a community.
To be closely tied to a community.
To have close bonds (ties) to the community.

To have bonds and ties to something does not actually imply knotting.

This works in all major varieties of English.